# Uncaught RangeError after adding on change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

My JS code was doing great until i added the following function :

```
   $(".meassure-combo").change(function() {
 switch ($(this).attr("name")) {
   case "bust-combo":
   case "shou-combo":
   case "wais-combo":
   case "hips-combo":
   case "imse-combo":
   $("[rel='"+$(this).attr("name")+"']").val( $(this).val() ).change();
   break;
 }
 switch ($(this).attr("rel")) {
   case "bust-combo":
   case "shou-combo":
   case "wais-combo":
   case "hips-combo":
   case "imse-combo":
    var type = $(this).attr("rel");
    var val = $(this).val();
   $("[name='"+type+"']").val(val).change();
    CL3D.interpolation(type,val);
   break;
 }
   });
```

after adding this code i started getting the following error in console

Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at RegExp.test ()

what is the problem and how can i solve it ?

thank you in advance

Comment: We don't know what the problem is when you don't explain what is expected and what is or isn't working and what errors exist. Please review [ask]

Comment: @charlietfl sorry for that i forgot to add the error. 
the error is :
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You have an event handler that is triggered from within itself, it's an infinite loop of sorts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.change()` is called within `change` event handler. If `$("[rel='"+$(this).attr("name")+"']")` or `$("[name='"+type+"']")` also have `.className` `"meassure-combo"` then result would be `Uncaught RangeError`.